# BOA hang - how to detect this and take action for this

Tags: linux, webserver, embedded, embedded-linux

I am having a SDK which has a boa webserver running in it to server HTTP requests.
It is seen that at times the BOA server hangs.
The boa server is not dead as it is shown in the device as running when i execute the "top" command.
How can we overcome this?
Is there any way we can know when the boa has hung so that we can restart the boa binary?

Comment: it is seen that such an issue arises, the CPU usage of the boa will shoot very high (above 60 %cpu usage) and also when looking at  the socket status using netstat,it is seen that a very high number of sockets are in  CLOSE_WAIT state.

Comment: can anyone update on this?